# Label size in map units, GeoServer .SLD file

Tags: geoserver, cartography, sld, units

Is it possible to define labels in map units in a GeoServer SLD file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is certainly possible for stroke widths using the Symbology Encoding (SE) enhancements. See this [page](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/uom.html?highlight=uom) for an example of how to do it.

That said I don't know if it works for labels, if it does may be you can add an answer here saying so.